# Prestashop - additional code when deleting a customer

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I would like to add the code associated with one of the modules that should be executed when the client is removed by the administrator in the back office. Where should I put this code? I cant find the right file.

[image: Code should be executed after clicking the 'Delete' button]

## Update

I added this code to the module for testing, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
public function hookActionObjectCustomerDeleteAfter($params)
{
    $customer_id = (int)$params['object']->id;
    PrestaShopLogger::addLog( 
        sprintf('Customer with id %d was deleted with success', $customer_id)
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Do you want to execute some code when a customer is deleted?

Comment: @idnovate Yes, that is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the right hook would be `hookActionObjectCustomerDeleteAfter` in some custom module. Don't forget to register your module to the hook before launching the code. You can do this during a module install process in `install` method with code `$this->registerHook('actionObjectCustomerDeleteAfter')`

Comment: I tried to use this hook - the module is listed in 'positions' so it should be fine, but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, the hook was not registered in the database. I put it there manually and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use hook `hookActionObjectProductDeleteAfter`.